# How to get glob() to return the same files order as opendir()?

Tags: php, opendir

I want `glob` to return same files order (sort) as `opendir`

For example:

```
$files = glob('/home/web/public_html/audio/*.mp3');
foreach($files as $file) {
 echo $file;
 break;
}

if ($handle = opendir('/home/web/public_html/audio/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GLOB_NOSORT` flag, which will make [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) return the files as they appear in the directory.

[`readdir`](http://php.net/readdir) doesn't sort the files, so `GLOB_NOSORT` would replicate this behaviour. From the docs:

> The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.

Comment: Could you post the output of both of them? Have your found any pattern in their sorting?